# Re-render page from JS Django Template

Tags: python, django

I have an endpoint that renders a template that has a list of movies

On the page, there is a button called "Add movie" and an input field to add the name of the movie. When the button is pressed, I want to add a movie of the name to the list of movies and re render the page.

Right now, I am doing it all in JS, with a fetch request, but I can't re render the page like this.

How could I achieve the effect I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the page without reloading/re-rendering the whole webpage using AJAX calls and changing a specific element inside the HTML's DOM. You can do this in raw Javascript or use some JS libraries to simplify the code. Here are some libraries you can consider if you've a large'ish project and such requirements might come up again:

- jQuery
- [intercoolerjs.org](http://intercoolerjs.org/)
- [unpoly.js](https://unpoly.com/)

Comment: Is this how it is most popularly done? or is it better to do it the way that Matthias said? Thanks for your help

Comment: Both will work. With Matthias' answer the whole page will reload, so user will see a slight stutter and page refresh (if the page size is large, it could take a while to refresh). Using one of the AJAX methods that I listed, you can 'update' say a single `<div>` or `<img>` element on the existing page, without having to refresh the whole page again.

Comment: I see. But I would also have to update my db... how would I do that from the js? Just make a post request with the fetch api?

Comment: Yeah, the Ajax request will basically call an API endpoint on the server to fetch some data too, just like any other server request. You can update the DB in that request. It's a lot to explain here you can read this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're rendering on the server-side, so in order to re-render, you need to send data back to the server. One way of doing this creating a form element which posts data to the same page when you click the button. And then on the server side, take the inputted movie, add it to the other movies, and then you can re-render and return.

This answer attempts to provide general guidance, since your question was general.

Comment: Hi this makes sense, how do I make the form go to a specific endpoint? Say that the page is being rendered on /movies which is a views function called movies(). Would the form also go to movies() or could I make it go to another endpoint/function. Does this question make sense?